# same Keybinds to opposite commands

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-keybinding

I would love to set my 'tranformTOLowerCase' and 'tranformToUpperCase' to the same keybind, and use the when clause option that vs code has, but I can't find the right property to rely on,

I'v looked in the vsCode documentation under when contexts and didn't find a solution,
Does anyone know any different way?

Comment: what is the context you are looking for

Comment: How are you going to differentiate the two?  Whether it is already uppercased or lowercased?  There is no context key that will detect that.

Comment: I know that threw the contexts I can't make differentiate the two, maybe my question wasn't right, I'm looking for another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any keybinding `context` key that will help to differentiate between text that is uppercase and text that is lowercase.

But you can use an extension that I wrote to do this: [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform&ssr=false#overview).

Create this keybinding in your `keybindings.json`:

```
{
  "key": "alt+d",                    // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {
    
    "find": "((([a-z])|([A-Z]))(.*))",   // is the first letter upper of lowercase?
    
    "replace": "${3:+${1:/upcase}}${4:+${1:/downcase}}",
    
    "isRegex": true,
    "matchCase": true,                 // this must be set to true to distinguish cases
    "restrictFind": "selections",      // works on your selection(s), one or many
  }
}
```

[image: toggle case keybinding]

As you can see, it tests the first letter.  If it is lowercase `a-z`, then the selection is uppercased.  And vice-versa, if the first letter is `[A-Z]`, then the selection is lowercased.

If you can have digits, underscores or other non-alphabetic characters as the first character, this simple first-letter matching won't work and you would have to keep testing characters which would make for a messy regex, but could probably be done.  [Let me know if you need that, I think I know how it can be done, although it is a different approach.]

The replacement:

```
"replace": ${3:+${1:/upcase}}${4:+${1:/downcase}}
```

is pretty interesting.  The `$n`'s refer to capture groups from the find regex.  `${3:+${1:/upcase}}` means if there is a capture group 3 (the first letter is `[a-z]`, then upcase all of capture group 1.

And similarly if the first letter is `[A-Z]`, so there is a capture group 4, then it and the rest of the selection, capture group 1, will be lowercased.

In a normal vscode snippet or keybinding you can not embed a capture group inside a conditional like `${3:+${1:/upcase}}`.  `${3:+text to add here if group 3}` normally takes only text and cannot resolve variables or capture groups, much less transform their case like `${1:/upcase}` inside the conditional - but the extension can.

Comment: very interesting, thank a lot for the explanation. Can I just paste the code to the file you mentioned or I must install the extension? (I'm currently work in Internal network)

Comment: It would only work with the extension.  As I mentioned, the necessary replace won't work anywhere in standard vscode so you would have to install the extension.  Also `findInCurrentFile` is this extension's contributed command.